# C++ ldap pagination

Tags: c++, pagination, ldap

I wrote ldap pagination according to the [ldap_Paginate_C++](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/ldap_create_page_control.htm) link, and then I compile it with the following command and then run it.

```
g++ -std=c++17 -o lpaginate ldap_pagiate.cpp  -L/usr/lib64/ -lldap -llber -g
./lpaginate
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ldap.h>
#include <lber.h>
#include <ldap_features.h>

#define         LDAP_SERVER "ldap://test.local" 
#define         LDAP_BASE "dc=test,dc=local" 
#define         LDAP_FILTER "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" 
#define         LDAP_PAGE_SIZE 2
#define         BIND_DN "testuser"
#define         BIND_PW "qweasdzx!@q"
#define         LDAP_TRUE 1
#define         LDAP_FALSE 0

int main ()
{
    int l_rc, l_entries, l_entry_count = 0, morePages, l_errcode = 0, page_nbr;
    struct berval  *cookie = NULL;
    char           pagingCriticality = 'T', *l_dn;
    ber_int_t*  totalCount;
    LDAPControl    *pageControl = NULL, *M_controls[2] = { NULL, NULL }, **returnedControls = NULL;
    LDAPMessage    *l_result, *l_entry;
    struct ldap* mldap;

    int ld = ldap_initialize(&mldap, LDAP_SERVER);
    if (ld != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf("Init of server %s failed.\n", LDAP_SERVER);
      return 0;
    }

    struct berval cred;
    cred.bv_val = ber_strdup(BIND_PW);
    cred.bv_len = strlen(BIND_PW);

    l_rc = ldap_sasl_bind_s(mldap, BIND_DN , NULL, &cred, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if ( l_rc != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
      printf("Unable to Bind to the LDAP server.  Return code is %d.\n", l_rc);
      return 0;
    }

    page_nbr = 1;
    int msgId;

    do {
        l_rc = ldap_create_page_control(mldap, LDAP_PAGE_SIZE, cookie, pagingCriticality, &pageControl);
        M_controls[0] = pageControl;

        l_rc = ldap_search_ext(mldap, LDAP_BASE, LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, LDAP_FILTER, NULL, 0, M_controls, NULL, NULL, 0, &msgId);
        if ((l_rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) & (l_rc != LDAP_PARTIAL_RESULTS))
        {
         printf("Failure during a search.  Return code is %s.\n", ldap_err2string(l_rc));
         ldap_unbind_ext_s(mldap, NULL, NULL);
         break;
        }

        l_rc = ldap_result(mldap, msgId, LDAP_MSG_ALL, nullptr, &l_result);
        if (l_rc == 0 || l_rc == -1) {
            if (l_result != nullptr) {
                ldap_msgfree(l_result);
            }
            break;
        }

        l_rc = ldap_parse_result(mldap, l_result, &l_errcode, NULL, NULL,
                                 NULL, &returnedControls, LDAP_FALSE);


        if (cookie != nullptr) {
            ber_bvfree(cookie);
            cookie = NULL;
        }
        l_rc = ldap_parse_pageresponse_control(mldap, *returnedControls, totalCount, cookie);

        if (cookie && cookie->bv_val != nullptr && (strlen(cookie->bv_val) > 0)) {
            morePages = LDAP_TRUE;
        } else {
            morePages = LDAP_FALSE;
        }

        if (returnedControls != NULL) {
            ldap_control_free(*returnedControls);
            returnedControls = nullptr;
        }
        M_controls[0] = NULL;
        ldap_control_free(pageControl);
        pageControl = NULL;

        if (morePages == LDAP_TRUE) {
            printf("===== page : %d =====\n", page_nbr);
        }

        l_entries = ldap_count_entries(mldap, l_result);

        if (l_entries > 0) {
            l_entry_count = l_entry_count + l_entries;
        }

        for (l_entry = ldap_first_entry(mldap, l_result); l_entry != NULL; l_entry = ldap_next_entry(mldap, l_entry)) {
            l_dn = ldap_get_dn(mldap, l_entry); 
            printf("%s\n", l_dn);
        }
        ldap_msgfree(l_result);
        page_nbr += 1;
    } while (morePages == LDAP_TRUE);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this code gives the following error:

> Failure during a search.  Return code is Not Supported.

The meaning of this error is that the order of calling the functions is wrong. That is, the order of calling the two functions ldap_create_page_control and ldap_search_ext is wrong.

Can someone help me and fix this LDAP pagination problem. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `if ((l_rc != LDAP_SUCCESS) & (l_rc != LDAP_PARTIAL_RESULTS))` does not do what you think it does. That applies a bitwise AND to the two conditions, essentially acting as a logical OR. I think you wanted `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: @paddy Thank you for your accuracy,
Do you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Did that not solve the issue?

Comment: @paddy No, not resolved. It gives the same error.

Comment: @paddy No, not resolved. It gives the same error.
When I set the call location of the two functions to ldap_create_page_control and ldap_search_ext as below, this error no longer occurs; But the value of the cookie variable becomes null, which causes a segfault later.

call ldap_search_ext ...
call ldap_create_page_control ...